# Xamarin.Forms - Difference between Button.TextProperty.PropertyName and nameof(myButton.Text)

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin.forms, nameof

Besides the syntax, is there *any* difference between:

```
Button.TextProperty.PropertyName //(Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty.PropertyName)
```

and

```
nameof(myButton.Text)
```

Is one preferred over the other for any reasons besides personal preference?

Answer (score 2):

In practice they will be the same value.

nameof() is a compile time value, while Button.TextProperty.PropertyName isn't necessarily.

Button.TextProperty is a statically allocated object with a PropertyName property.

nameof() will be compiled into the source and likely be a faster access depending on your compiler optimizations.

Comment: I would add that `PropertyName` is a property of `BindableObject` and will be available only for this type (And it's hard-code-declared when creating the BindableProperty and thus it's not necessarily the compile time value)